# D3 adding text lables to horizontal stacked barchart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Hi Thanks to FernOfTheAndes for answering this. I have another query. Please see FIDDLE and original question below.

My question is, how do I add text labels to the example below. Ideally I would like the values to be displayed in the rectangles. However, for stacked bar graphs the process seems to be different in that, nested array information doesn't seem to be picked up.

For example

```
var dataset = [
[{
    x: 0,
    y: 20 // test with different values
}],
[{
    x: 0,
    y: 30 // test with different values
}],

[{
    x: 0,
    y: 50 // test with different values
}]
```

];

How do I get 20, 30 , 50 to be displayed in their respective rectangles?

Grateful if someone could update the FIDDLE or paste the full code of what I need to do in order to add the text labels.

Original code below:
[D3 Horizontal stacked bar chart axis cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967118/d3-horizontal-stacked-bar-chart-axis-cut-off)

FIDDLE: http://
jsfiddle.net/zDkWP/

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do. Since you already have `groups` as your nodes, you just need to append `text` elements to them, using the same scale that you used for the rectangles. To place your text within the rectangles, you will need a little offset on both `x` and `y`, particularly on `y`. For demo purposes, I hardcoded an offset for the `y` by adding 20 to it, but you should user smarter offsets for both dimensions.

```
var text = groups.selectAll("text")
    .data(function (d) {
        return d;
    })
  .enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr("class","text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return xScale(d.y0); // could use an offset here as well...
    })
    .attr("y", 70) // just added 20 as an offset...for demo purposes
    .text(function(d) { return d.y;});
```

And a little CSS to help:

```
.text {
    fill: white;
}
```

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7sxmH/).

Comment: Thanks again for this! I did try something very similar but failed on three counts.

Comment: 1. in .data() I entered .data(dataset) assuming it was calling the dataset. I am struggling to understand why a function is needed in the .data attribute since you are only calling the dataset but picking the values from the .text attribute. 2. I didn't create a new variable called text but tried to append groups.selectAll("text"). How does creating a new variable text automatically execute the d3? Must be grouping?  and finally 3. put my code after the callAxis bit. Not sure if that made any difference. I am learning a little more each day! Cheers.

Comment: For item 2, there is really no need to create the text variable since we are not leveraging it anywhere else, you can simply do `groups.selectAll("text")...`. For item 3, the order makes no difference since there are no dependencies between the two segments of code in question. For item 1, I cannot explain it better than [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#group)...but do read the whole page...very illuminating.